# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty\frac{dl}{(r^2+l^2)^{\frac32}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How to evaluate the following integral
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{dl}{(r^2+l^2)^{\large\frac32}}$$

The solution is supposed to look like this, unfortunately I can't derive it.
$$
\left[\frac{l}{r^2\sqrt{r^2+l^2}}\right]_{l=0}^\infty
$$

Comment: Wolphram Alpha premium account -> input integral -> step by step solution. This is not a physics problem.

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$ for all formulas. The "formula" in the image is just unreadable.

Comment: Did you try substitution? E.g. $y = l^2+r^2$?

Comment: Since $ l$ is the variable of integration, substitute $l = r\tan \theta$.

Comment: If you know the solution to the indeterminate integral, then differentiate and see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

Let $l=r\tan{u}$, then $dl=r\sec^2{u} \ du$. The integral becomes
$$\frac{1}{r^2}\int^{\pi/2}_0\frac{\sec^2{u}}{\sec^3{u}}du=\frac{1}{r^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

All integrals of the form $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{k-1}}{(x^n+a^n)^m}dx$ can be expressed in terms of trigonometric functions

as follows: first, let $x=at$, then $u=\dfrac1{t^n+1}$. Now recognize the expression of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in

the new integral, and finally use Euler's [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties) in order to arrive at

the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int\frac{dl}{\left(r^2+l^2\right)^{3/2}} = -\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\int\frac{1}{\left(r^2+l^2\right)^{1/2}}dl
$$
change of variables $v=l/r$
we find

$$
-\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\frac{1}{r}\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{1}{\left(1+v^2\right)^{1/2}}rdv = -\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\left[\sinh^{-1}v\right]^{\infty}_{0}
$$
$$
-\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\left[\sinh^{-1}v\right]^{\infty}_{0} = -\frac{1}{r}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+v^2}}\frac{dv}{dr}\right]^{\infty}_{0} = -\frac{1}{r}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{l}{r}\right)^2}}\left(\frac{-l}{r^2}\right)\right]^{\infty}_{0} 
$$
which leads to your result.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(x^2+r^2)^{3/2}}$$
Let $xr=\tan u$. Therefore $dx=\frac1r\sec^2u\ du$:
$$I=\frac1r\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sec^2u\ du}{(r^2\tan^2u+r^2)^{3/2}}$$
$$I=\frac1{r^2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sec^2u\ du}{(\tan^2u+1)^{3/2}}$$
$$I=\frac1{r^2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sec^2u\ du}{(\sec^2u)^{3/2}}$$
$$I=\frac1{r^2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sec^2u\ du}{\sec^3u}$$
$$I=\frac1{r^2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{du}{\sec u}$$
$$I=\frac1{r^2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos u\ du$$
$$I=\frac1{r^2}$$